# using implode for array inside mysql where in clause

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to use array for mysql where in clause

```
$result= $myDB->query("SELECT sum(total) as total FROM ".$myDB->prefix("mydata")." WHERE categoryname IN ('".$categoryname."') AND year='$year' AND stat_id='$stat_id'");
```

current ouput for the categoryname is

```
('Cat1,Cat2,Cat3')
```

desired output

```
('Cat1','Cat2','Cat3')
```

i tried it like so far but its not working

```
$categoryname_new = implode(',',$categoryname);

$result= $myDB->query("SELECT sum(total) as total FROM ".$myDB->prefix("mydata")." WHERE categoryname IN ('".$categoryname_new."') AND year='$year' AND stat_id='$stat_id'");
```

Comment: Maybe `$categoryname_new = "'" . implode("','",$categoryname) . "'";` placeholders would be easier and more secure.

Comment: The implode function returns a single string, in order to put quotes around each word in this string you will need to either manipulate your array before imploding, or apply some regex to the produced string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the naive solution will be:

```
$array = ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3'];
echo "'" . implode("','", $array) . "'";
```

but it could introduce sql injection, so you need properly escape data in array first

sample one-line with escaping:

```
echo "'" . implode("','", array_map('mysql_escape_string', $array)) . "'";
```

note: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, you need to use `mysqli_*` which require connection link

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar a while ago using `array_map`, hope it helps:

```
$args = array_map(function($a) {
    return sprintf("'%s'", $a);
}, $args);

$args = join(",", $args);
```

The above code will iterate over the array and modifies every single element to surround it with `''`. Finally, I join the array with `,`.